# swift firebase create child WITHOUT childByAutoId

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an online iOS app and I need to know the User's name and number and the online Users name and number, so I made the User struct have a childByAutoID to add the child name and number when its created. but the issue is I am trying to count the online users and display it on my ViewController, so my idea is to make the Online User json struct be added upon login in and removed when sign out, so I made the name + phone be the parent for the name and number in the Online Users struct, but I every time I try to access it from the sign out Viewcontroller the var name + number comes back empty so I can't remove it from firebase database without the child ID

I don't want to use childByAutoId for online User because I can't figure out how to store the key, since I am using async functions which makes it too complex on how to retrieve it too

```
//1st view controller
func getID() -> String {
    return String(nameField.text! + numberField.text!)
}

@IBAction func linkTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if (nameField.text != nil && numberField.text != nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Phone Number", message: "Is this your phone number? \n \(numberField.text!)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
            PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber("+1 " + self.numberField.text!, uiDelegate: nil) {
                (verificationID, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                    print(self.numberField.text ?? "no number entered")
                } else {
                    getID()
                    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                    defaults.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVID")
                    defaults.synchronize()
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "code", sender: Any?.self)

                    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Users").childByAutoId()
                    let values = ["Name": self.nameField.text, "Phone": self.numberField.text]
                    ref.updateChildValues(values as [AnyHashable : Any], withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                        if err != nil {
                            print(err as Any)
                            return
                        }
                        print("user saved into firebase db")
                    })

                    let ref2 = Database.database().reference().child("Online Users")
                    let onlineRef = ref2.child(self.getID())
                    onlineRef.updateChildValues(values as [AnyHashable : Any])
                }
            }
        }
        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addAction(cancel)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "You left me empty", message: "please fill your name and number", preferredStyle: .alert)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

// 2nd view controller

```
@IBAction func signOutFunction(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        let newVar = ViewController()
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Online Users")

        ref.child(newVar.getID()).removeValue()

        self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } catch let error {
        print("not signed in...", error)
    }
}
```